# Debug error. R6010 abort has been called()

Tags: c++, debugging, abort

```
#include "../../../std_lib_facilities.h"
```

int main()
{

`vector <int> nmb;
vector <int> rep;
vector <int> prt;
int flag = 0;
int temp = 0;
int br = 0;
int max = -1;
int ind = 0;

cout << "Enter as much integers as you like\n";
while (cin >> temp)
{
    if (nmb.size() == 0)
    {
        nmb.push_back(temp);
        prt.push_back(temp);
        ++rep[br];
        ++br;
    }

    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nmb.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (temp == nmb[i])
            {
                ++rep[i];
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0)
        {
            nmb.push_back(temp);
            prt.push_back(temp);
            ++rep[br];
            ++br;
        }
        else if (flag == 1)
        {
            flag = 0;
            prt.push_back(temp);
        }
    }

}

cout << "You've entered numbers\n";
for (int j = 0; j < prt.size(); ++j)
    cout << prt[j] << " ";

for (int k = 0; k < rep.size(); ++k)
        if (rep[k] > max)
        {
            max = rep[k];
            ind = k;
        }
cout << "\n\nMost repeated number is " << nmb[ind] << endl;}`

My task is to write what number has been entered max times. I know it's probably not the best idea but it was the first "good" one I had so I went with it. It compiles fine but gives me that error from that title when running. I tried cout << in few places and it seems that problem starts at the beginning of while loop.

Comment: `rep` is empty when you do this: `++rep[br];`.

Comment: isn't it set to 0 by default? I thought I was just setting rep[0] = 0 to rep[0] = 1?

Comment: `rep[0]` is not a thing if `rep` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to access the first element of `rep`, which is an empty vector.

You have to actually add elements before you may access them. Right now you're reading from and writing to memory that is not yours.